# Handler.postDelayed inside onCreate of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-handler

I have an Activity which contains a lot of views and fragments, It nearly opens in about 850~ ms as warm or hot startup, Cold startup 1250~ ms.

What I made to reduce this time to nearly 350~ ms is post delaying my views initialization as the following:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        initUi();
        bindDataToViews();
    }, 50);
}
```

My question is:

1- Does the previous code have any side effects that won't be visible immediately.

2- Any suggestion or better implementation would be appreciated

Comment: Does the previous code have any side effects that won't be visible immediately : No
Any suggestion or better implementation would be appreciated: try to ignore handler until you need most.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to improve the performance of your UI, you can follow the Android guidelines to do that:https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/.
You can also start using FrameLayouts instead RelativeLayouts as described here https://academy.realm.io/posts/gotocph-daniel-lew-efficient-android-layouts/. If you definitely cannot use FrameLayout, you must use ConstraintLayout. With those basic steps, you will improve the performance of your app.

I recommend to you measure the app performance before and after the changes. You can find some tools here: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/. I have used dumpsys and GPU profiler, those are very cool!